# How do I scroll a active element of a list into view?

Tags: jquery, css

Basicially I like to make the active element always visible.

The active element in this example has the classes `option todo`

How could this be done if you click on the button `scrolltoactive` with jQuery?

Thanky you,

Alex

```css
body {
   font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
}

ul.variant-scroll{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 55px;
  padding: 0 0 0 20px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  counter-reset: section;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

ul.variant-scroll li{
  display: inline-block;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  color: #6056c3;
  padding: 0 25px;
  height: 55px;
  line-height: 55px;
  font-size: 1.142em;
  cursor: pointer;
  pointer-events: auto;
  margin: 0 -4px 0 0 !important;
}

ul.variant-scroll li.todo{
  background: #6056c3;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: default;
  pointer-events: none;
}

ul.variant-scroll li.todo a{
  color: #fff;
}

ul.variant-scroll li.notdone.todo,
ul.variant-scroll li.checkout{
  background: #f2f2f2;
  color: #525252 !important;
  cursor: default;
  pointer-events: none;
}

ul.variant-scroll li.notdone.todo a,
ul.variant-scroll li.checkout a{
  color: #525252 !important;
}

ul.variant-scroll li::before {
  counter-increment: section;
  content: counter(section) ". ";
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="scrolltoactive">Scroll to active</button>

<ul class="variant-scroll">
<li class="option">option</li>
<li class="option">option</li>
<li class="option">option</li>
<li class="option">option</li>
<li class="option">option</li>
<li class="option">option</li>
<li class="option">option</li>
<li class="option">option</li>
<li class="option">option</li>
<li class="option todo">option</li>
<li class="option notdone todo">option</li>
<li class="option notdone todo">option</li>
<li class="option notdone todo">option</li>
<li class="option notdone todo">option</li>
<li class="option notdone todo">option</li>  
<li class="option notdone todo">option</li>
<li class="option notdone todo">option</li>
<li class="option notdone todo">option</li>
<li class="option notdone todo">option</li>
<li class="option notdone todo">option</li>
<li class="option notdone todo">option</li>
<li class="option notdone todo">option</li>     
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hm33uk08/).

You can use the property `scrollLeft()`

Like this : `$('.variant-scroll').scrollLeft($('.todo').offset().left)`

### EDIT

If you want it to work after click on the button simply add an event listener to your button :

```
$('.scrolltoactive').on('click',function(){
    $('.variant-scroll').scrollLeft($('.todo').offset().left);
});
```